# CP search for entries by postDate?

Tags: entries, control-panel, search, postdate

Does the control panel search support postDate, expiryDate, dateCreated, dateUpdated?

For a custom date field, the below will return all dates in October 2017:
`customDate:2017-10`

But for entry attributes like postDate it returns nothing:
`postDate:2017-09`

Sure would be good to be able to search by these date values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the `postDate` of an entry is not indexed for search.

Kind of hacky, but you could make a custom DateTime field with duplicate information (i.e. `myPostDate`) and do a search based on that.